# Does the maintenance plan or the notify operator task support failure notification?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I want to notify an operator upon failure of the maintenance plan.

I know that I can configure the alerts via the agent job. But I am looking to configure the alert in the maintenance plan itself. I have added the notify operator task in the maintenance plan. However it doesn't have any option to set whether the notification must be sent upon success/failure/completion.

Does the maintenance plan or the notify operator task support failure notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no option for email on failure at the maint plan level. You have to do that either *inside* the plan adding tasks as explained below or modify the Agent jobs (not recommended).

One option is to modify the main plan (not the agent job) and add "Notify Operator Task" task(s) and connect an "On Failure" control flow from each task to this/these "Notify Operator Task" task(s). You won't get the report file in the email, though.

This is one of many reasons why many of us prefer alternative solutions, like for instance Ola Hallengren's maintenance solution. https://ola.hallengren.com/

Comment: Please can you clarify what you mean by "not the way that the regular maint plan emailing work."?

Comment: I modified and added a bit to that paragraph above.

Comment: Will either of the below help me to send the email for failure notification for my scenario: 1. set up notify operator task upon task failure in maintenance plan; 2. configure failure notification on the job.

Comment: Yes, both allow for that. Notify Operator Tasks is what I referred in my answer above, but I had the wrong name for the task name (not corrected). Another options is to add a failure notification for the job, but we don't recommend that you modify the jobs that are created by a maint plan.

Comment: Interesting, what's the reasoning to not recommend modifying the Job created for a Maintenance Plan, especially with something rather benign like enabling Notifications?

Comment: Modifying the job to add failure notification is the only possible way for me to notify the operator when the job fails (due to the job owner being a decommissioned user for example). Even though you say it is not recommended, it looks like it is the only option for failure notifications in such case.

Comment: Why can't you modify the maint plan and add "Notify Operator Task" to do the emailing? Anyhow, the reason I recommending against modifying the jobs is that you never know what happens the next time you edit the maint plan. Will they be re-created? etc...

Comment: I can't add "Notify Operator Task" to do the emailing because it wont handle the situation where the maintenance plan owner doesn't exist and so the job fails to execute, and this failure will never be notified to the operator because the maintenance plan never ran.